# Read data from an active system activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

I am working on an app that opens the Network Settings screen, where available networks search takes place (done automatically), after which I would like to read the activity's data.
Meaning, when all the networks that were found, appear as options on the Network Settings Activity's screen, I would like to get a feedback, somehow, and to read the data on the screen.

Listening to the logcat is not possible since 4.1 (if i'm not mistaking), and bottom line, even with the READ_LOGS permission, I can't do it on my Android 4.3 device. (Solved my problem before)

If so, is such a thing possible, and how?

Comment: What exact info do you want to receive from this Setting Screen?

Comment: The names of the networks that were found - this would be good, but any feedback regarding success / failure would suffice